# Cython different results

Tags: python, cython

Why this function in cython returns different results for every run?

I passed in 50000 for test

```
cpdef int fun1(int num):
    cpdef int result
    cdef int x
    for x in range(num):
        result += x*x
    return result
```

edit:
so now I changed it to long long result like this

```
cpdef long long fun1(int num):
   cdef long long result = 0
   cdef int x = 0
   for x in range(num):
       result += x*x
   return result
```

and it returns 25950131338936
but :) the python func

```
def pyfunc(num):
    result = 0
    for x in range(num):
        result += x * x
    return result
```

return 41665416675000

so hm so what is wrong?

Comment: Don't you need to initialize result, before you start adding to it?

Comment: yes thx for letting me know I thought it default to 0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are probably two problems here. First, result should be initialized to zero. Secondly, the result is the sum of all integers squared from 0 to 50 000 (non-inclusive)

[image]

The problem is that the storage type `int` cannot fit such a big number. Try using a larger storage type like `long long` and it will work. The maximum value a 32-bit integer can hold is roughly 2^31. The maximum value a `long long` can hold is typically 2^63. Consult the C compiler on the system at hand to figure out the exact limits.

Comment: Good point, but this doesn't explain why the function "returns diffrent results for every run".

Comment: I included your comment. Thank you for catching that.

Comment: cpdef long fun1(long num):
    cpdef long result = 0
    print(result)
    cdef long x
    for x in range(num):
        result += x*x
    return result

Comment: i get the result 
-61063496

Comment: and the python version returns 1249975000 and yes the print return 0

Comment: You need to use the `long long` type. It is guaranteed to hold at least a (signed) 64 bit value.

Comment: Oh! it is called long long sorry about that. thank you

Answer (score 0):

The **cdef** statement is used to declare C variables, either local or module-level.

So you need to set the initial value to the `result` variable. If you don’t, it gets what it found in memory at call time, which can be anything.

```
cpdef int fun1(int num):
cdef int result = 0
cdef int x
for x in range(num):
    result += x * x
return result
```